# Running a command with python using subprocess

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess

I would like to run in Python the following command, using the package subprocess.

```
cd C:\Users\...\csv
attrib +U -P /s
```

In my mind I would like to do something like

```
import subprocess
cmd = [r'C:\Users\...\csv','attrib +U -P /s']
pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

when I run this I don't have any error, but also nothing happens, therefore I assume there's a mistake in the code.
Thanks

Comment: Asking the same question, that was already closed, will yield the same result. You need to provide more details. What error are you getting, more details. We cannot guess.

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker Yes, we can guess what it is the OP wants to do because they have specified the two commands they wish to execute and we see what the Python code they are using to implement it and can plainly see that it is wrong and can deduce the error it would produce, namely the OP wants to `cd` to a directory but is using the directory name as a command name to be executed.

Comment: This looks like a repost of this [How to run two commands in one subprocess call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449000/how-to-run-two-commands-in-one-subprocess-call)

Answer (score 1):

As you have it, you are trying to execute a command named `csv` rather than changing directories to the `csv` directory. If you wish to change directories and then run the `attrib` command, try:

```
import subprocess
import os

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\...\csv')
cmd = 'attrib +U -P /s'
pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, text=True)
out, err = pro.communicate()
print(out, end='')
```

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the answer and indeed in that way it works. But my question is if I can do everything without using the os.chdir command. A way of running a command in certain directory using subprocess. The reason is because the folder is a OneDrive folder therefore when I run "os.chdir(r'C:\Users\...\csv')" it download all the files contained in the folder. I hope this helps to understand why I need to do it in that way.

Comment: What about specifying the directory path in the command: `cmd = r'attrib +U -P C:\Users\...\csv /S'` Does that work? But why did you do a `cd` in your question?